# Can't turn on Sense Hat

Tags: gpio

I was trying to disable Sense Hat's function of IMU by writing python code.

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(2,GPIO.HIGH)
```

This was very successful because now when I try to use accelerometer, it will report "IMU Init Failed"

However, I tried to turn on the Sense Hat by writing the opposite code.

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(2,GPIO.LOW)
```

But there is no effect, the IMU unit still can not be turned on and it is still reporting "IMU Init Failed" Error. I have to take it off and plug it in again so I can reuse it.

Is there any way to solve this problem. Thank you so much!